# Numpy.Loadtxtx CSV- Wrong Number of columns error- CSV plotting issue

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am working with exported CSV data from SNAP (SAR coherence/intensity/phase). After processing my data in SNAP I exported the final product as a CSV file. The file should be exporting each pixel in the final product in the CSV file as a new row with 4 column, first column is Feature ID, second Intensity, third Phase, and fourth Coherence.

The issue I am running into is that the export has not been 100% successful and there are a few pixels which do not contain a Feature ID and export themselves into the same row as the previous pixel, so that these "error rows" have 7 columns, first column is Feature ID, second Intensity, third Phase, fourth Coherence, fifth Intensity, sixth Phase, and seventh Coherence.

As these files should have approx 100,000,000 pixel I want to write a python script that can correct this error. I would like to find a way, when np.loadtxt encounters a "wrong number of columns" error that the additional columns will be read as a new row beginning at the second column. Any ideas?

Comment: `loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) accept input from anything that can feed them lines.  I often demonstrate them with a list of lines obtained from the copy-n-paste.  Opening the file, and passing the lines through your own filter script also works fine.  So basic Python code, read a line, pass it on, or split it and pass the two lines separately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to clean the CSV file separately from loading it with numpy:

```python
import csv

in_path = "in.csv"
out_path = "out.csv"

with open(in_path, "r") as in_file, open(out_path, "w") as out_file:
    in_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    out_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row in in_reader:
        out_writer.writerow(row[:4])
        rest = row[4:]
        while rest:
            out_writer.writerow(["", *rest[:3]])
            rest = rest[3:]
```

This also handles the edge case where you have multiple erroneous pixels in a row, assuming the extra fields also get appended in the same manner.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help and suggestions, however it hasn't cleaned the data successfully. Any other suggestions?